# Creating a property that is determined by another style's property

Tags: css, html, dreamweaver

### Is there anyway to have a sub style's property be determined by another styles property? For example

```
.sidebar #menu{
width:100%;
}
.sidebar #menu #Sub{
left:(.sidebar #menu.width)px;
}
```

---

So in this case the submenu would be positioned to the right of the menu element. This isn't exactly what I am coding but this is the general concept that I need to use in my menu. This way no matter what size their screen is the sub menu will always be right beside the main menu. FYI I am new to css, so if you know the answer please explain it at a beginners level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend jQuery in this example. Use the following:

```
$(".sidebar #menu #Sub).css("left", $(".sidebar #menu").css("width"));
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I did run into an unexpected problem but figured it out. When you would resize the window then the sub menu would be out of place so I fixed it with this code.    $(document).ready(function(){                                       
$("#navMenu li li").css("left",$("#navMenu").css("width"));        });
$(window).resize(function(){                                        
$("#navMenu li li").css("left",$("#navMenu").css("width")); 
});This was my actual code but the li li is the subMenu of the navMenu.(ps sorry I don't know how to style the code in the comments)

Answer (score 1):

Only if you use something like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/).  CSS itself directly doesn't support this currently.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the rest of your site's structure and layout, you may be able to use

```
.sidebar #menu #Sub{
    left:100%;
}
```

Comment: I think this may have worked but I didn't try to fix it once I resized the window, but good idea